# libGDX: take screenshot inluding ShapeRenderer

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to take screenshots in my libGDX game using [the code from the official wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Taking-a-Screenshot).

My render method looks like this:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, topColor, topColor, bottomColor, bottomColor);
shapeRenderer.end();

batch.begin();
// everything else
batch.end();

if (screenshot) { takeScreenshot(); }
```

But unfortunately, the ShapeRenderer rect in the background is missing in the screenshots.

Any idea, why?

Comment: What are you seeing instead of your background? Your screenshot actually looks different than what is on screen?

Comment: Yes, it's different. On the screen I see a color gradient as background and the screenshot has a transparent background. Maybe the shapeRenderer object is not a part of the FrameBuffer? Like being on another layer?

Comment: Maybe set your clear color's alpha to one instead of leaving it as the default of zero. Evidently, whatever blend mode you're using with ShapeRenderer is leaving the alpha channel unmodified.

Comment: Do you mean to replace the first line by `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);`? This doesn't change my screenshots.

Comment: Don't replace it, add that line before the call to glClear

Comment: Ok, I added that line and it still doesn't work. I forgot to mention that I compile for the desktop. (Sorry for tagging android.) When I run my game on Android, the screenshot looks as expected. But I need the screenshots in my desktop version.