# LibGDX screenshot strange behaviour

Tags: java, libgdx, screenshot

I encountered a rather strange behaviour of screenshotting my desktop application in LibGDX. I remade a small program to reproduce this "bug" which only renders a black background and a red rectangle. Those images are the results:

[image] [image]

The left one being a screenshot from window's screen clipping tool, this is what it looks like running the program. The right is from the screenshot code I posted a little further down. To clarify, I want the program's screenshot to get the left image's result, without the transparency getting all weird.

This is my render code, don't mind the coordinates. Since I can see the rectangle being rendered perfectly, it makes no sense to me for the error to be in the render method. But I'm posting it anyway.

```
@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    shape.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    shape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    shape.rect(0, 0, 300, 300);

    shape.setColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.5f);
    shape.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    shape.end();

    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);

}
```

This is the code to take a screenshot:

```
public static void screenshot() {

    Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    PixmapIO.writePNG(new FileHandle(Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath() + "screenshots/test.png"), pixmap);
    pixmap.dispose();

}

private static Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    final Pixmap pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h);

    // Flip the pixmap upside down
    ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
    int numBytes = w * h * 4;
    byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
    int numBytesPerLine = w * 4;
    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        pixels.position((h - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
        pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
    }
    pixels.clear();
    pixels.put(lines);

    return pixmap;
}
```

I went and researched, I only found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146088/libgdx-take-screenshot-inluding-shaperenderer), which is exactly same problem. It has slightly less information and no answer, though. I hope someone of you can answer this mystery.

Comment: It's not a bug. The screenshot from code includes whatever alpha is in the back buffer at the time, which is not visible on screen at runtime because you have an opaque window.

Comment: Use premultiplied alpha, draw to a FrameBuffer and then draw the FrameBuffer to screen with blending off, or manually replace the alpha of each pixel in the pixmap before saving it.

Comment: Don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but this might work. When you're about  to take a screenshot, first change the blend function to GL_ONE, GL_ONE. Then draw a black opaque rectangle over the whole screen. I think that should ensure the alpha is one everywhere without affecting the colors (since RGB of black is 0, adding it to your scene won't change RGB, but the opaque color means you're adding alpha of 1 to everything). Then call your screenshot method to take the picture.

Comment: If you wanted to replace alpha everywhere on your Pixmap after you've taken the screenshot, you could call `getPixels()`, then set every fourth byte in the ByteBuffer to (byte)255. But actually I think the above approach would be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My question was answered *23rd Feb 2017* by [Tenfour04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506796/tenfour04) but as he shows no interest in posting his solution as an answer, I am doing it to solve this thread. Huge thanks to him. What I did was to set every fourth element (the alpha value) in the `ByteBuffer` returned by `getPixels()` to `(byte) 255` (opaque) this was my result:

```
private static Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int width, int height) {

    final Pixmap pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, width, height);

    ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
    for(int i = 4; i < pixels.limit(); i += 4) {
        pixels.put(i - 1, (byte) 255);
    }

    int numBytes = width * height * 4;
    byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
    int numBytesPerLine = width * 4;
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        pixels.position((height - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
        pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
    }
    pixels.clear();
    pixels.put(lines);
    pixels.clear();

    return pixmap;
}
```